# Static page on Wordpress site returning 404 error (htaccess file help)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, .htaccess, ftp

I have a Wordpress site and would like to have a static landing page on the same domain, custom coded and without any Wordpress 'influence'.

I've done this before on other servers with no issues, so I uploaded the files via the FTP in root/subfolder, so the page would be:

> domain.com/subfolder/index.php

However when I try to load the page, it either:

- shows the Wordpress header/footer and a 404 error
- or it takes forever to load and wont load any css, images, etc...

If I try to access any files within the subfolder then it's the same outcome.

I looked into it, and apparently this could be an issue with the *.htaccess* file not allowing pages 'outside the box'. My *.htaccess* file at the moment is:

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

    # END WordPress

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    # Wordfence WAF
    <Files ".user.ini">
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all denied
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </IfModule>
    </Files>

    # END Wordfence WAF
```

I tried adding this line which I found may work:

> RewriteRule ^(.*)index.(php|html?)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]

But after I tried it the whole site wouldn't load.

I also tried the [WP Custom HTML Page plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-custom-html-pages/#developers) but:

1. It only allows you to add a html page and no accompanying folders (css, js, images, etc...)
2. It didn't even work - it displayed the page as if it were a blog post with the Wordpress header/footer

I can't find anything else which may work, so any help is appreciated.